# php separate iframe inside paragraph

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have this code:

```
<p> paragraph </p>
<p> another paragraph 
<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GXIAE">
</iframe></p>
```

How can i take the iframe out from the paragraph into like this :

```
 <p> paragraph </p>
 <p> another paragraph </p>
 <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GXIAE"></iframe>
```

I have tried by using regex below but doesn't work

```
   $string = preg_replace('<p[^>]*>[^<]*\K(<iframe[^>]*><\/iframe>)(.*?<\/p>)','$2$1', $string);
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML tags with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Give your `<iframe>` and your `<p>` an id, then refer to them via their ids.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323252/php-split-the-images-inside-p-tag) with a fake account.

Comment: i really need the solution... please help

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<iframe>` and your `<p>` an id, then refer to them via their ids. You can then do whatever you want with them, like "moving" one of them.

Comment: i was working facebook instant article for my website, but the iframe not showing because the iframe inside the paragraph tag.